# Can't show id from join

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, outer-join

this is controller

```
$list['eskul'] = $this->m_crud->join1("eskul","waktudaftar","waktudaftar.id_eskul=eskul.id_eskul")->result();
```

this is model

```
function join1($table1, $table2, $query1){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($table1);
        $this->db->join($table2, $query1, 'left outer');
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

In database, table waktudaftar is NULL, but in table eskul NOT NULL. I want to show id_eskul in my view but it's NULL. Please can someone help me

Comment: can you at least make things more clear

Answer (score 1):

You have the same column name *id_escul* in 2 tables. Therefore you need to create an alias for the *id_escul* from your second table, as this is the one you want to see the results from, if you don't you always see the result for id from the first table:

```
$this->db->select('*,'.$table2.'.id_escul as myID');
```

Comment: Glad it worked. On Stack Exchange sites the way to say *thank you* is to 
[upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the tick mark on the left. You're free to switch later when a better answer comes along.